# Oracle-speed up query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

This query find what W_G of K2 is(ex: 'L_E' is found by'E1').
Then it find what K1 is(ex: 'IS' is found by 'E1').
Then it find what K4, K5 depending on K1,K2('30','10' by 'IS' and 'C01A').

To speed up this query, Are there any things to modify this query?

Execution plan is as below.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                           |     1 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|   1 |  VIEW                        |                           |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL          | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6617_CD798E |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|   3 |    TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION |                           |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|   4 |     LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6618_CD798E |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL       | C_W_B                     |     1 |   273 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|   6 |       VIEW                   |                           |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL     | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6617_CD798E |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|*  8 |     VIEW                     |                           |     1 |    39 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|   9 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL       | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6618_CD798E |     1 |   273 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|  10 |      SORT AGGREGATE          |                           |     1 |    13 |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|  11 |       VIEW                   |                           |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|  12 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL     | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6618_CD798E |     1 |   273 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|  13 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION   |                           |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|  14 |   LOAD AS SELECT             | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6617_CD798E |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|* 15 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | C_W_B                     |     1 |    78 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
|  16 |   FAST DUAL                  |                           |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          4  recursive calls                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
         16  db block gets                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
         30  consistent gets                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
          2  physical reads                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
       1156  redo size                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        682  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        416  bytes received via SQL*Net from client                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
          0  sorts (memory)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
          0  sorts (disk)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
          1  rows processed
```

Tabel is below

```
CREATE TABLE C_W_B  (  
      HE VARCHAR2(22),
      WE VARCHAR2(22),
      G_D VARCHAR2(22),
      W_G VARCHAR2(22),
      W_V VARCHAR2(22),
      K1 VARCHAR2(22),
      K2 VARCHAR2(22),
      K3 VARCHAR2(22),
      K4 VARCHAR2(22),
      K5 VARCHAR2(22),
      K6 VARCHAR2(22),
      K7 VARCHAR2(22),
      K8 VARCHAR2(22),
      K9 VARCHAR2(22),
      K10 VARCHAR2(22),
      K11 VARCHAR2(22),
      K12 VARCHAR2(22),
      K13 VARCHAR2(22),
      K14 VARCHAR2(22),
      K22 VARCHAR2(22),
      K16 VARCHAR2(22) 
      );
```

Data as below

```
 INSERT INTO C_W_B(HE,WE,G_D,W_G,W_V,K1,K3,K4,K6) VALUES 
('C6','61','R3','L_C_F','1','IS','C01A','30','10');
INSERT INTO C_W_B(HE,WE,G_D,W_G,K1,K2) VALUES 
('C6','61','R3','L_E','IS','E1');
```

Query is as below

```
WITH G_S AS (
  SELECT /*+FIRST_ROWS(1)*/
  A.W_G, A.K1
  FROM C_W_B A
  WHERE 1=1
  AND A.HE = 'C6'AND A.WE = '61'  AND A.G_D ='R3'  AND A.K2='E1'
 )
 SELECT CASE
 WHEN (SELECT A.W_G FROM G_S A)='L_E'
 THEN (
    WITH SEO AS (        
 SELECT A.K1 FROM G_S A
          ),
     SE AS (SELECT *
         FROM C_W_B B
         WHERE B.W_G = 'L_C_F'
         AND B.HE = 'C6'
         AND B.WE = '61'
         AND B.G_D ='R3'
         AND B.K1 = (SELECT K1 FROM SEO)
         AND B.K3 LIKE 'C01A'
        ) 
SELECT (L_T /QT*1000) 
      FROM ( SELECT NVL(TO_NUMBER(K4),0)  AS  L_T,
        NVL(TO_NUMBER(K6),0)  AS  QT
       FROM SE
       WHERE W_V IN (SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_NUMBER(W_V))) FROM SE )
        )
          )
   WHEN 1=2
     THEN TO_NUMBER(0)
  ELSE TO_NUMBER(0)
  END
 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What is the access time for this query now?

Comment: There is much useless stuff in your query. For example `TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_NUMBER(W_V)))`, Why circle around with number and char?  Obviously CTE `G_S` returns just one row - replace `dual` with `G_S`. Personally I don't like these embedded sub-queries. Maybe try to put all tables in one ` FROM` clause. I don't think you need more than 1-2 sub-queries.

Comment: are the statistics of the table up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be simplified and may give performance as following:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN W_G ='L_E' 
            AND K6 IS NOT NULL -- ADDED K6 IS NOT NULL CONDITION TO AVOID NUMBER DIVIDE BY 0 ERROR
       THEN NVL(K4,0) / (K6*1000)
       ELSE 0 
       END  
 FROM (SELECT A.W_G, B.K6, B.K4,
           ROW_NUMBER() 
           OVER (ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(W_V) DESC NULLS LAST) AS RN
      FROM C_W_B A JOIN C_W_B S ON (A.K1=S.K1)
     WHERE A.HE = 'C6'
       AND A.WE = '61'
       AND A.G_D ='R3'
       AND A.K2='E1'
       AND S.W_G = 'L_C_F'
       AND S.HE = 'C6'
       AND S.WE = '61'
       AND S.G_D ='R3'
       AND S.K3 LIKE 'C01A')
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Cheers!!